# My file won't write to the text file, it just prints below

Tags: python, file

I have tried several different approaches but I cant seem to fix it. At the bottom, it just creates the .txt file but adds neither of the variables and remains empty. It then begins to print the username and password below the rest of the code in shell. [Enters the username and password and prints below whilst the .txt file remains empty.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgDxB.png)

```
un = input("What is your username?")

npw = input("Please enter new password.")
npwc = input ("Please confirm new password")

if npwc == npw:
    if npwc.isupper()== False:
        if npwc.islower()== False:
            if len(npwc) >= 8:
                if str.isdigit(npwc) == False:
                    npw=npwc
                    print("Your paswsword has been changed")
                else:
                    print("Your password must contain a number")
            else:
                print("Your password must contain at least 8 characters.")                
        else:
            print("Your password must contain at least 1 upper case character.")

else:
    print ("Passwords don't match")

pw = npwc

file=open("PasswordSheet.txt","a")
file.write(input(un, ", ", pw))
file.close()
```

Comment: Are you sure you should have `input` inside the `file.write`? Testing without it I was able to have the required data appended to the file.

Comment: Suggest you read (and heed) [_How to debug small programs_](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 2):

```
file.write(input(un + ", " + pw))
```

Should be

```
file.write(un + ", " + pw)
```